# How to add background image to row of grid

Tags: extjs4

How do I add a background image to a row of my grid? I can change the row's colour with the below code but it doesn't add the image?

```
    this.getView().getRowClass =  function(record, rowIndex, rowParams, store) {
            return record.get("deleted_dts") ? "rowdeleted" : ""
    };
```

The CSS:

```
   .row-deleted { background: url("../images/bin.png") no-repeat right center #eeeeee; color: gray; }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selector must target the cell element ('td'), not the row element ('tr'):

```
.row-deleted .x-grid-cell { 
    background: url("../images/bin.png") no-repeat right center #eeeeee;
}
```